# How to echo the last query after eloquent model in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I am deleting an item like this. The delete method is excuting well but I can't echo the last executed query.

```
public function deleteItems(Request $request){
        $query=null;
        switch($request->category){
            case('categorylist'):
                $category = category::find($request->id);
                $query=$category->delete()->toSql();
                break;

            default:

        }
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>2, 'msg'=>'Successfully deleted', 'query'=>$query->toSql()));
    }
```

Comment: in your 'echo' statement try 'query'=>$query .... without (toSql())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toSql()` method works only on instances of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` ( query builder as it is usually called ). Methods like `where()`, `orderBy()` etc return an instance of query builder, hence `toSql()` works on them. The `delete()` method does not return an instance of query builder ( I think it returns Boolean or the id it deleted. Can't remember ). So the `toSql()` method won't work.

If you just want to get the last executed query, then you could use `DB::getQueryLog()`. For example

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$category->delete();
$queryLog = DB::getQueryLog();
// Now $queryLog will contain all the SQL queries which were executed after the DB::enableQueryLog()

$last = end($queryLog);
$query = $last['query'];
$bindings = $last['bindings'];
```